# Java usecase of overloaded version of Class.forName()

Tags: java, reflection, overloading

What is the use of overloaded version of `Class.forName()`?

```
public static Class<?> forName(String name,
                       boolean initialize,
                       ClassLoader loader)
                throws ClassNotFoundException
```

Can anyone please give one example where it is preferred to use.

**Edit:**

Refer below code.

```
Class  clz=(Class)Class.forName("com.test.classloader.MyClass", false, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

        MyClass mc=(MyClass) clz.newInstance();
        System.out.println(mc.TEST);
        System.out.println(mc.i);
```

**MyClass:**

```
public class MyClass {

static String TEST="MYCLASS";
static int  i;
static{
    i=20;
}

}
```

Why it prints

`MYCLASS`

`20`

Comment: The javadoc is quite good for that method. Did you have a look at it?

Comment: Yes, But my question is with boolean initialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use this method if you want to load the `Class` with a specific `ClassLoader`, which is passed via the `loader` parameter.

Also the `initialize` boolean will state if you want the class to be initialized or not.

Quite straightforward.

Comment: What do you mean by initialize ? initialization of variables?

Comment: Initialization is a [step in the ClassLoading process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Concepts.doc.html#19075). It's where the class variables are set to their default values.

Comment: @amicngh The class has to be initialized at some point. In your example it will be when you create the instance, instead of when the class is loaded. Please read the link I posted in my above comment.

Answer (score 0):

The intialise is whether to call the static block at that point or not.

If you use any static fields or methods, you have to call the static blocks so you don't see the behaviour.

What you can do is add a debug output in the static block and your example to see the order they are called. (Or add an exception to the static block)

Comment: I think what he's asking is why is the static block executed when he's specifying that the class not be initialized in `forName()`.

Comment: Which I thought I answered. ;) It isn't initialised in the `forName` but it is initialised before it can be used.